# 'undefined' when trying to get messages layout in framework 7, how to?

Tags: javascript, popup, message, html-framework-7

I have a popup that loads some html for messages. When I open the popup and trying to get the html, i get `undefined`.

see this http://codepen.io/patrioticcow/pen/LZNraz

this doesn't seem to work:

```
$$(document).on('opened', '.popup-messages', function() {
  var mMessages = $$('.messages')[0].f7Messages;
  console.log(mMessages);
});
```

this doesn't work either

```
var myMessages = myApp.messages('.messages', {autoLayout: true});
console.log(mMessages);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no attribute f7Messages inside $$(.messages)[0], Instead of that you can use innerHTML. ie :

```
 var mMessages = $$('.messages')[0].innerHTML;
console.log(mMessages);
```

Hope this helps.
By the way,why you need html?Use messageBar concept of framework7.

Comment: if you care enough to update the code pen using basic `messageBar` concept, i would appreciate it. Thanks